# Someone quitted smoking sometime ago, yet there is still a possibility that he may start smoking again

Tags: tense, past-tense, infinitives, past-simple

Someone quitted smoking sometime ago, yet there is still a possibility that he may start smoking again. In this case I know that I cannot say "He used to smoke 2 years ago." because that would certainly mean he is never ever going to smoke again. I remember the case that my teacher was explaining it years ago, I remember that 'used to' cannot be used, but I can't remember which tense I should be using.

Comment: _He hasn't smoked for two years_.

Comment: It sounds to me like: 'He hasn't smoked for two years but now he is smoking again', am I wrong ?

Comment: _He hadn't smoked for years and then he started again._  ---  _He hasn't smoked for two years._  ---  _He died of cancer but hasn't ever smoked._  ---  _(also see my Answer below)

Comment: @Red - I think you're wrong. Perhaps if I said, "He didn't smoke for two years," that could imply that he picked up the habit again after a two-year hiatus.

Comment: What @J.R. said (and then some! :). Imho you're *completely* mistaken in supposing that ***used to*** has any inherent implications of ***will never do again***.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

✘  `Quitted" is not a word and is never used..

✓  He quit smoking 2 years ago.

✘  He used to smoke 2 years ago.

✘  He use to smoke 2 years ago.

✓  He was a smoker 2 years ago.

✓  Bob quit smoking 2 years ago.

---

**None** of these imply that he will never start smoking again.

`*used to*` and `use to` can be confusing.  They are very common phrases, are often mixed up with each other, and can mean many different things.

- `Use to` is normally followed by a verb.
- `Used to` normally refers to the past. (Hence the `ed` at the end.)

---

**These are all correct**:

> - I **used to** smoke.   ☜   I smoked *in the past*.
> - I **use to** be a smoker.   ☜   I smoked *in the past*.
> - I am **used to** smoking.   ☜   I know how to do it.
> - I'm **used to** my tools.   ☜   I am *familiar* with them.  I've had them for a long time.
> - Gloves are **used to** keep your hands warm.   ☜   The *purpose* of gloves is warmth.
> - He was **used to** cook and clean.   ☜   He was "taken advantage of".

---

Here are [some tips and even an online quiz](http://www.5minuteenglish.com/mar20.htm) to see if you understand a little better now. :)

Comment: I see it (quitted) here: https://www.google.it/search?client=ubuntu&hs=c7N&ei=aW4MWp-mBIG0kwW02ouYCg&q=quitted&oq=quitted&gs_l=psy-ab.3..35i39k1j0i67k1j0l4j0i10k1j0l2j0i10k1.3982.4741.0.4871.7.7.0.0.0.0.93.591.7.7.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..0.7.590...0i46i67k1j46i67k1.0.Kez8L5a0w7k

Comment: What @Red fx said. It's not common (especially today), but the full subscription-only OED entry for ***quit*** includes *Inflections:   Past tense and past participle **quit, quitted.***

Comment: *Weird,* it does list it.  "Quitted" sounds 100% wrong to me.  @J.R.? Anyone else have an opinion on that?  I wonder if it's a regional thing, perhaps used in the the Southern USA but not in Canada.

Comment: I feel bad for people who have to learn English as a second language, because there are so many rules that make no sense, and other rules that get broken all the time, and slang that's more common than correct grammar.  I find it interesting answering these questions because I have to think hard about words that I use every day, and remind _myself_ of "correct" English. @FumbleFingers, how would you use _quitted_ in a sentence?

Comment: @ashleedawg You mark as wrong "He used to smoke 2 years ago" and I'm not sure why.  I agree it's not beautiful English but it sounds natural to me.  Am I missing something?

Comment: I do not think all the native English speakers know the rules and use them correctly anyway. I have encountered way too many people who do not even know how to pronounce the letters correctly.. I mean it is basic yet some do not know it

Comment: @Andrew I do not mark it wrong, but I remember that my teacher said it is not the case to use it because he may start smoking again. That's why I asked the question, to be sure. :)

Comment: Ah ok, acccording to [this post](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/60474) it is a regional difference (I gather it's Canada+Britain vs. USA) and also has changed dramatically over time.  (Its easy to forget how many "formerly proper" words are no longer used, like [_thine_](https://www.google.it/search?client=ubuntu&site=async/dictw&q=Dictionary#dobs=thine))

Comment: @Redfx  The only way to suggest the person will *definitely*, *never* smoke again is to use the word "permanently" (or a synonym).  "Two years ago he **permanently** quit smoking".  Even then, there's always a chance.  As they say in groups like Alcoholics Anonymous "Once an addict, always an addict".

Comment: @Andrew - there's no such thing as "definitely, 100%, never again" especially with addictive substances, but maybe that's a bad example.  I am definitely never having any more kids.  (But I guess we wouldn't say "_I used to be a parent_".)  Okay now I'm just going to confuse matters, I'm stepping out for a smoke.  :)   But last question: was my example correct: `He was **used to** cook and clean. ☜ He was "taken advantage of"` or would that be "He was used, to cook and clean."?

Comment: @ashleedawg: To be honest, I personally would be unlikely to use ***quitted*** in *any* context today. But in those (relatively rare) contexts where it means ***relinquish, let go of***, such as the most recent citation in OED ([*The capturing king must complete its move and be **quitted** before any of the captured pieces is removed*](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/156786?rskey=Su9fNP&result=4#eid)), I'd definietely prefer that version over ***quit***. But my point was simply that *is not a word* is a bit of an overstatement.

Comment: @ashleedawg Well, without the spoken intonation it's confusing, but once I parsed it out it looks fine.  Note the pronunciation of "used" in *"I used to dance"* and *"I was **used** to dance"* is different.

Comment: @Andrew: Professional linguists (incl. John Lawler, both here and on ELU) will tell you that *nobody* really knows how to "conjugate" ***be used to***. There no consensus on how to write something like *When you were a child, did you **use / used** to like school dinners?* (and no clues to be found in the spoken version, since *in practice* they sound identical).

Comment: @Andrew Honestly, until 40 minutes ago, I thought **"used to"** was correct in all of those cases, and mistakenly thought that **"use to"** is _never_ correct.  (And I recently scored 97% on a college level English placement test!)  This site is interesting; I wonder what other words I'm using wrong that never get corrected...  Thank you Red-fx, my English improved because of you!

Comment: @FumbleFingers -- I would assume the basic rules of "correct" English are changing at accelerated speed since texting and emailing (and comments on forums) have become commonplace, and I suppose all that matters is that we get our point across.

Comment: @ashleedawg: I think the entire *concept* of "correct use of English" has undergone immense upheaval in my lifetime. The boffins got more or less nowhere for decades with getting computers to understand natural language, all the time they were trying to explicitly encode grammar/syntax "rules" with the help of grammarians and linguists. Once they gave up that approach and just let neural nets figure out all that stuff for themselves, things have advanced at a dizzying pace.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - artificial speech like Siri & Google haven't come much farther than [Eliza](http://psych.fullerton.edu/mbirnbaum/psych101/Eliza.htm) in the 60's, but I am curious how language will evolve over the next 3 or 4 generations. Pen and ink are gone, and I can only assume spoken-word will eventually come to an end too.  In the meantime, my intention of helping _others_ learn English on this site has resulted in my own learning experience. Like ***[boffin](https://goo.gl/yPyvGu)***...never heard that term before today.  I guessed you were British before I confirmed on your profile. :)

Comment: @ashleedawg: You presumably haven't noticed the *huge* advances in natural language processing over the last 2-3 years! [Real-time language translation](https://techcrunch.com/2017/10/04/googles-airpods-competitor-do-real-time-language-translation/) is now a reality, thanks to neural-net-powered AI (*not* significantly aided by decades of work in computational linguistics - if anything, I think that focus actually held things back). My point being that "correct English" will probably just end up being too much trouble - our smartphones will speak the same as we do, not how we ***should***.